# where can I find an overview of known "multithreading systems architectures" design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, multithreading, system

Using C#, I have been doing multithreaded development for about 5 years, and consider myself quite proficient (I wrote my own lock-free queue and task parallel framework before Microsoft made TPF).

However, I find it incredibly difficult to find information on practical multithreaded system design patterns anywhere. There are some good resources on low-level algorithms and collections, but not much on system design.

So to the question, anyone know where this information can be found?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939928/oo-design-patterns-for-multi-threaded-synchronisation

Comment: i should have clarified the title a bit, i was looking for "multithreaded system architecture" design patterns...     so i'll be parsing the answers with this in mind....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET: Design Patterns for Decomposition and Coordination on Multicore Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735651590)

This is a book, I recommend wholeheartedly.

It is:

- New - published last year. Means you are not reading somewhat outdated practices.
- Short - about 200+ pages, dense with information. These days there is too much to read and too little time to read 1000+ pages books.
- Easy to read - not only it is very well written but it introduces hard to grasps concepts in really simple to read way.
- Intended to teach - each chapter gives exercises to do. I know it is always beneficial to do these, but rarely do. This book gives very compelling and interesting tasks. Surprisingly I did most of them and enjoyed doing them.

Comment: this seems like a good starting point boris, thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), by [Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/) is a good starting point.

Please consider the book [.NET Multithreading](http://www.manning.com/dennis/) too.